parametric optimization in differential equation through gradient descent
I need to solve a differential equation containing a parameter $n$, and based on a constraint I assign, I would like to find what is the value of $n$.
I would like to use a gradient descent method.
Problem. Solve:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ny,\ \ \ \   (1)$$
where $y(x)$ is the unknown, defined on the domain $[0,l]$ and $n$ is a real parameter not dependent on $x$ (to be optimized).
The boundary condition is $y(x=0)=1$.
I would like to find out what is the parameter $n$ so that we have $y(x=l)=b$, where $b$ is a real, number.
I know that the aforementioned equation is very simple, and an analytical solution exists. However, I would like to use the gradient descent method on a very simple case, to test it. Later I need to pass to a more involved differential equation.
Questions. How can I implement the algoritm?
What is the cost function to write?
Do I need to introduce also a Lagrange multiplier to account for the contraint dictated by Eq. 1?
During each computational step of the algorithm, can n be constant, or should I allow n to become a function of x?
Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards.

To write this as an optimization problem, I will instead reformulate the endpoint condition as a quadratic function $\frac{1}{2}(y(\ell) - b)^2$. We then have a constrained optimization problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_n& \frac{1}{2}(y(\ell) - b)^2 \quad \text{such that} \\
y'& - ny = 0, \ \forall x\in(0,\ell), \  y(0)=  1.  
\end{aligned}
$$
We proceed via the method of Lagrange multipliers. The Lagrangian function is
$$
L(y,p,n) = \frac{1}{2}(y(\ell) - b)^2 + \int_0^\ell (y'(x) - ny(x))p(x)~dx.
$$
The variational derivatives with respect to $p$, $y$, and $n$ yield
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_p\hat{p} &= \int_0^\ell (y'(x) - ny(x))\hat{p}(x)~dx \\
L_y\hat{y} &= (y(\ell) - b)\hat{y}(\ell) + \int_0^\ell (\hat{y}'(x) - n\hat{y}(x))p(x)~dx \\
&=  (y(\ell) - b)\hat{y}(\ell) + \int_0^\ell (-p'(x) - np(x))\hat{y}(x)~dx + p(\ell)\hat{y}(\ell) - p(0)\hat{y}(0) \\
&= (y(\ell) - b + p(\ell))\hat{y}(\ell) + \int_0^\ell (-p'(x) - np(x))\hat{y}(x)~dx \\
L_n\hat{n} &= -\hat{n}\int_0^\ell p(x)y(x)~dx,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\hat{p}(x)$, $\hat{y}(x)$, and $\hat{n}$ are perturbations of the adjoint, state, and parameter repsectively. Note that since the set of functions satisfying $f(0) = 0$ is a linear space, we can choose state perturbations $\hat{y}(x)$ such that $\hat{y}(0) = 0$ so that $y + \hat{y}$ satisfies the original initial condition, which is why one of the boundary terms disappears in the second derivative equation. The last expression can be interpreted as a directional derivative, so the gradient w.r.t. $n$ is given by $-\int_0^\ell p(x)y(x)~dx$, where $y$ and $p$ satisfy the state and adjoint equations, respectively.
Now the stationarity conditions state that any critical point of this functional occurs when all of these derivatives are zero for all values of the perturbations. Furthermore, since the obective is convex, this critical point corresponds to a minimum. By setting each of these expressions equal to zero for every possible perturbation, we obtain the pointwise conditions
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_p\hat{p} = 0 \ \forall \hat{p} \implies & y' - ny = 0, \ y(0) = 1 \\
L_y\hat{y} = 0 \ \forall \hat{y} \implies & p' + np = 0, \ p(\ell) = b - y(\ell) \\
L_n\hat{n} = 0 \ \forall \hat{n} \implies & \int_0^\ell p(x) y(x)~dx = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now perform gradient descent in the following way. We start with an initial guess for $n$, the perform the following steps:

Solve the state equation $y' = ny, \ y(0) = 1$.
Solve the adjoint equation $p' = -np, \ p(\ell) = b - y(\ell)$.
Update $n$: $n_{new} = n + \alpha \int_0^\ell p(x)y(x)~dx$.
Repeat

This type of method tends to scale very well to high-dimensional or expensive ODE solves because it only requires 2 solves per iteration.
Edit: I wrote this out as an optimization problem beacuse that is what it seemed like you wanted in your post, but the problem you originally posed is more of a rootfinding problem and could be better solved via Newton's method or some sort of shooting method. It will almost certainly perform better than this, but this is how you do ODE-constrained optimization and this will work even in the cases where the strong problem $(y(\ell) = b)$ is not well-posed.

Thank you very much for your useful suggestion. I tried and it works (even if the boundary condition I requested was y(x=0)=1, otherwise the solution was identically 0, but never mind).

As for the ultimate purpose of my question, I have to solve the wave equation in frequency domain $\nabla^2 E=-\omega^2 n^2/c^2E$ for the electric field, and I would like to optimize the refractive index $n(x,y)$ in one domain so that the electric field is funneled into a small spot (something like a converging lens). Of course, before going towards this very complicated case, I needed to try the optimization in a very simple case, to learn how it works. This was the case. Thank you very much again for your help.

The expressions for the PDE case will actually be pretty simple for your equation because it is self-adjoint. The adjoint equation will just be another Helmholtz equation.

Do you think there are differences if the target is a maximization
rather than a minimization?
I have to solve the equation $\nabla^2 E(x,y)=-\omega^2 n^2(x,y)/c^2 E(x,y)$ in a domain $D$, with some boundary conditions.
I want to optimize $n(x,y)$ in a domain $U\subseteq D$ so that the integral $\int_{-s}^s |E(x,y)|^2/E_0^2 dx$, calculated on a segment from x=-s to x=+s at a fixed $y=y_0$, is maximum. $E_0$ is a complex constant (incident electric field amplitude)
From the physical point of view, I want to maximize the light intensity focused on that segment.

Do you have an idea? Thank you very much anyway for your help

That sounds reasonable, you'd just have to adjust your gradient update to increase rather than decrease the function. It isn't obvious to me that such a problem would have an attainable maximizer, but you are free to try and find out

Thank you for your reply. To do that, is it enough to change the sign of $\alpha$ constant in the update rule for $n$ (Point 3 of your algorithm)? As for the maximization, I am not aiming at finding the global maximum, but just a local maximum is enough. In other words, also considering the fabrication defects of a real device, I am satisfied to find a configuration in which at least 80% of the incident light converges. It is not required that 100% of the incident light converges.

I was following the suggestion from @whpowell96, that was very useful. However, I was stuck when I tried to use this method for a variant of this problem. In the new case I have  the equation $dy/dx=n_1y$ for $0\leq x\leq a$, while for $a<x\leq l$ the equation is $dy/dx=n_2y$, with $n_1<n_2$ (both these are real). $y$ is continuous in $a$ and $y(x=0)=1$. I would like to find the optimal $a$ so that $y(x=l)$ is maximum.

I was trying to replicate the suggestion of @whpowell96 , but I have difficulties in calculating the functional derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to the parameter a. Can you help me? Thank you for your attention.

Differentiating a functional with respect to an interface location seems more involved. I would suggest asking a new question

Thanks, I'll do it. Please have a look to my new questions to find it out.

I have created a new question for this problem. In case it might be of interest for you (@whpowell96), you can find it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4960733/599175
