How to differentiate a functional with respect to the interface location?
I have to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=n(x)y$$
defined for $0\leq x\leq l$.
$n(x)$ is a piecewise function so that
$n(x)=n_1$ for $0\leq x\leq a$ and $n(x)=n_2$ for $a < x\leq l$. $n_1$ and $n_2$ are two real, positive constants so that $n_1<n_2$.
The solution of the differential equation $y$ is continuous in $a$ (but its derivatives are not) and I assign the boundary contidion $y(x=0)=1$.
The target of my problem is to find the optimal value of $a$ so that I can maximize $y(l)$. I was following the approach proposed in the answer to my previous question: parametric optimization in differential equation through gradient descent. In doing this, I have to write a functional:
$$L(y,p,a)=\frac{1}{2}|y(l)|^2+\int_0^l\left[y'(x)-n(x)y(x)\right]p(x)dx,$$
where $p(x)$ is a Lagrange multiplier. Also $p$ is continuous in $a$, but its derivatives aren't.
Then, by calculating the functional derivatives of $L$ with respect to $p$ and $y$, I obtain two differential equations to be solved, that give me the value of $y(x)$ and $p(x)$. Once I know the values of the latter functions, I can evaluate the increment of the parameter $a$ (to increase $y(l)$) by calculating the functional derivative $\delta L/\delta a$. I am not able to calculate the latter expression.
So the question is: is there an analytical closed expression for $\delta L/\delta a$?
Can you help me?
Despite the fact this problem has a simple (and maybe more direct) analytical solution, I believe that my question is still relevant. Indeed, in the future I will have to move to a more involved differential equation, where no analytical solutions are available. Hence, before going to the more complicated case, for me it would be very useful to understand this method in a very simple case, where the analytical solution for benchmark is present.
Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards.

Notice that we can write $n(x;a) = n_1 + (n_2-n_1)H(x-a)$, where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. Interpreted as a distributional derivative, we have $\frac{d}{dx}H(x) = \delta(x)$. This would then lead to $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}n(x;a) = -(n_2-n_1)\delta(x-a)$. We then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_a(y,p,a)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^l -n(x;a)y(x)p(x)~dx \\
&= \int_0^l (n_2-n_1)\delta(x-a)y(x)p(x)~dx\\
&= (n_2-n_1)y(a)p(a).
\end{aligned}
$$

Thank you very much for your reply. It sounds good. However, I still have a doubt: in the original Lagrangian there was also the first part of the integral, reading $I=\int_0^ly'(x) p(x) dx$ (here I call it "I" for the sake of simplicity), where $p(x)$ is continuous in $a$, but $y'$ is not. Why is $\delta I/\delta a=0$? Thank you very much

None of the components you list directly depend on $a$ in the adjoint formalism. We have eliminated the constraint entirely by introducing the Lagrange multiplier. Everything is free to be varied within their respective spaces. $y$ is only related to $a$ through the state equation, obtained when deriving the stationary conditions for the Lagrangian. The continuity only matters when you are deciding what a solution to the state equation means, since it has a discontinuous RHS

Thank you very much for your help. This clarifies all my doubts. I hope we can get in touch again with you in the future for other mathematical problems. Cheers
